# How to remove focus from a ion-input in Angular 2+/Ionic2+

Tags: angular, mobile, input, ionic2, focus

It is possible to set focus using setFocus method from nativeEloment.

But how about remove focus?

How could I remove the cursor from and unselect an input from a template in a Angular 2+/Ionic 3 app?

I need to remove the focus because the mobile keyboard keeps open while a input has focus.

**Edit: The input is a ion-input of Ionic2+.**

Comment: how about blur()?

Comment: I forgot to say it's a ion-input. So it's do not have blur() and focus() int its native element.

Answer (score 9):

1) Add a template variable reference to your input in your component's template:

```
<ion-input #textInput>
```

2) Add `ElementRef` and `ViewChild` to your component's imports:

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
```

3) Add `@ViewChild` variable and relevant methods to your component:

```
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('textInput') textInput;

  setFocus() {
    this.textInput.nativeElement.focus();
  }

  removeFocus() {
    this.textInput.nativeElement.blur();
  }

}
```

You can trigger `setFocus()` or `removeFocus()` in a number of ways. Here's an example:

```
# app.component.html

<ion-input #textInput>

# app.component.ts

import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {

  [previous code elided for readability]

  isInputActive: boolean;

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  handleClickEvent(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (document.activeElement !== this.textInput.nativeElement) {
      this.textInput.nativeElement.blur();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say it's a ion-input. So it's do not have blur() and focus() int its native element.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/), it should work: What's the return value of `this.textInput`? But the issue is related to `(mouseover)` and `(mouseout)`. I'll remove that from the example!

Answer (score 3):

**For Ionic 4 users ;)**

After trying multiple solution to dismiss/hide the keyboard of a search input, I found a way inspired from your solution @zach-newburgh.

Was not working :

- `this.keyboard.hide()`
- `#searchInput
  (keyup.enter)="searchInput.blur()"`
- `this.searchInput.nativeElement.blur();`
- `this.searchInput.getElementRef().nativeElement.blur();`

**Only working solution**

```js
this.searchInput._native.nativeElement.blur();
```

---

### Complete solution

#### TS way

ts

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TextInput } from 'ionic-angular';

...

@ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput: TextInput;

...

onSearchEnter() {
    this.searchInput._native.nativeElement.blur();
}
```

html

```html
<ion-input #searchInput
           type="search"
           (keyup.enter)="onSearchEnter()"
           [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"></ion-input>
```

#### HTML and fastest way

html

```html
<ion-input #searchInput
           type="search"
           (keyup.enter)="searchInput._native.nativeElement.blur()"
           [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"></ion-input>
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on ionic 5

```
this.searchInput.getInputElement().then((input) => {
  input.blur();
});
```

Comment: Thanks James D. Your method works and help me solving the unfocus issues in Ionic 5.

Answer (score 1):

Apply focus and remove Focus Based on condition:

```
if (condition) {
  this.addressLine1.nativeElement.focus();
}else{
  this.addressLine1.nativeElement.blur();
}
```

Comment: As in the question it's mentioned that `it's a ion-input. So it's do not have blur() and focus() int its native element.` this answer won't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare veiwChild with one public variable
@ViewChild('myActionForm', { static: false, read: ElementRef }) public actionForm: ElementRef<any>;
**add set Timeout with in the method**
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.actionForm.nativeElement.click();
        }, 100);
```

Comment: Don't just paste a block of code with no supporting information. [How to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)